# Stop iframe from going fullscreen on android/phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, fullscreen

I am writing a mobile android application under phone gap and am having a problem with using an iframe:

I have a standard page that contains an iframe which loads content dynamically (not really important at the moment). The issue im facing is that on some emulators (strangely the newer ones) the iframe loads and instantly takes over the entire page meaning that my headers/footers disappear.

I works exactly as expected on some emulator devices and behaves as stated on others. Any ideas how i can stop this happening? I found this snippet:

```
super.appView.setWebViewClient(new CordovaWebViewClient(this, super.appView) {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But am unsure where it is supposed to go. Any ideas/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ian

Comment: Ok, its pretty simple really, just put the above snippet in your activities onCreate handler and all works fine.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException... Does this Snippet work ?

Comment: Confirmed, this snippet actually works for enabling iframes - just put it into onCreate and don't forget to import android.webkit.WebView;

Comment: +1 on the snippet, just encountered this problem, and it seems to work!